# How would I calculate sum of digits in the number (a^b)?

Tags: exponentiation

I was doing a question from a site,project euler specifically.I came to a question in which I was asked to **calculate sum of digits in number 2^1000**.Since I program very often I was able to do that question by making array and calculating as We used to do in elementary school.But I was not convinced because How a student calculate that if he/she don't know programming.I mean it is completely biased question isn't it ?

I am asking if there is any way to calculate **digit sum in general (a^b)**[a to the power b].For student who don't have programming background.

P.S:- If anybody wants to see implementation.I can post here

Comment: You mean a single iteration of digit sum or over and over until it's less than 10?

Comment: @ZelosMalum : no, it's the sum of the digits. It's this problem : https://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=016. About the question : Project Euler problems are problems where you need to use a computer. Now the question is : is your algorithm efficient, would you be able to calculate the digit sum of $2347^{789524642}$ with it?

Comment: @Tryss Looks like my algorithm cannot make it :)Atleast c++ cannot make it.I have to switch to java or python for that

Comment: @thoughtfulme : I'm not surprised, this number is very big, it would take around 2Go to store the number as a string ;) By the way, I don't know if there exists an efficient algorithm to do this 0:)

Answer (score 2):

It's a one-liner in Maple:

convert(convert(2^1000, base, 10),`+`);

You could look up OEIS sequence [A001370](https://oeis.org/A001370).
Or you could just ask [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20digits%20of%202%5E1000).

But if you're asking for a way of doing it by hand, I very much doubt that there is any.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a way to find the sum of the digits of $a^b$ when written in base $p$ where $p$ is prime and $p$ is a divisor of $a^b$. Denote by $v_p(n)$ the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorisation of $n$ and $S_p(n)$ the sum of the digits of $n$ when written in base $p$. By Legendre's Formula,

\begin{align*}
v_p(a^b!)=\dfrac{a^b-S_p(a^b)}{p-1} &=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lfloor{ \dfrac{a^b}{p^i} \rfloor} \\
\implies{}S_p(a^b)&=a^b-(p-1)\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lfloor{ \dfrac{a^b}{p^i} \rfloor}.
\end{align*}

But this formula cannot give a way to solve it by hand and even if there was one its going to be large and messy.